# How to split a string based on tab but not within quotes?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to separate a string that looks like this

```
'190-1\tbla-bla\tall_right\t"dont\tseparate me"\toooo').
```

The question how can I split it by tabs not concerning what is in quotations `""`. So the output is:

```
190-1,  bla-bla,   all_right,  "dont\tseparate me",  oooo
```

The answer was given by Scott Mermelstein:

```
line for line in csv.reader(infile):
```

Note the [] around the string in the answer on the other page.

**EDIT**

Answer was by @Scott Mermelstein

use the line `for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')`: If this gets reopened, I'll convert this comment to an answer.

Note the `[]` around the string in the answer on the other page. If your line is only `infile = '190-1\tbla-bla\tall_right\t"dont\tseparate me"\toooo'`, you'll get the result you describe. If your line is `infile = ['190-1\tbla-bla\tall_right\t"dont\tseparate me"\toooo']` and you modify the reader line as above, you'll get the right result

Comment: @Wiktor_Stribizew I don't think duplicate question answers it.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I nominated this for reopening.  While we can use a CSV reader, using the answer from "the dupe question" doesn't do it on its own.  We at least need to tell the reader to use tab as the separator.

Comment: @Marcel - in the interest in getting you moving, refer to the "dupe answer", and instead of the line `for line in csv.reader(infile):`, use the line `for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):`  If this gets reopened, I'll convert this comment to an answer.

Comment: It doesn't work as well. It takes each character instaed of separating using delimiter.

Comment: Note the `[]` around the string in the answer on the other page.  If your line is only `infile = '190-1\tbla-bla\tall_right\t"dont\tseparate me"\toooo'`, you'll get the result you describe.  If your line is `infile = ['190-1\tbla-bla\tall_right\t"dont\tseparate me"\toooo']` and you modify the reader line as above, you'll get the right result.

Comment: Yes,adding brackets indeed that worked. I add it into edit.